# Returning a value in Firebase onDataChange

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write a firebase app that contains a simple ArrayList that will serve as feed for a list view.
In order to do so I have a singleton that takes care of FirebaseConnection and will fetch the data. This data is then feeded to the list. The problem is the data is first feeded to the list as null then the data is finished retrieving. Any solutions you might have for me?

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList< Event > getAllEventsOnFirebase() {
    final ArrayList< Event > events = new ArrayList<Event>();

    DatabaseReference eventsTable = getDatabaseTableWith(Constants.tableEvents);

    eventsTable.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                HashMap<String, Object> event = (HashMap<String, Object>) postSnapshot.getValue();

                String eventId = (String) event.get(Constants.taEventUUID);
                String eventName = (String) event.get(Constants.taEventName);
                String eventAddress = (String) event.get(Constants.taEventAddress);


                Event newEvent = new Event(eventId, eventName, eventAddress);

                events.add(newEvent);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return events;
}
```

Also the way I populate the list is as follows:

```
   eventsArray = FirebaseConnection.getInstance().getAllEventsOnFirebase();

    EventListAdapter adapter = new EventListAdapter(this, eventsArray);
    eventsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is loaded asynchronously from Firebase. Luckily you can populate the `ArrayList` at any moment, as long as you tell the adapter that you changed it by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
public ArrayList< Event > getAllEventsOnFirebase(final EventListAdapter adapter, 
                                                 final ArrayList<Event> events) {
  DatabaseReference eventsTable = getDatabaseTableWith(Constants.tableEvents);
  eventsTable.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String eventId = postSnapshot.child(Constants.taEventUUID).getValue(String.class);
            String eventName = event.child(Constants.taEventName).getValue(String.class);
            String eventAddress = event.child(Constants.taEventAddress).getValue(String.class);

            Event newEvent = new Event(eventId, eventName, eventAddress);

            events.add(newEvent);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
  });
}
```

Now you can call it as:

```
ArrayList< Event > events = new ArrayList<Event>();
EventListAdapter adapter = new EventListAdapter(this, eventsArray);
eventsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

FirebaseConnection.getInstance().getAllEventsOnFirebase(adapter, events);
```

Comment: thanks that helps, but since I am getting the Firebase data in a SingletonClass, while the adapter is in the Activity is there a way to inform the adapter without having to pass it as a method parameter(this won't be possible since the adapter is not yet set at the time of passing the method). Or is this bad practice to do it in the Singleton Class?

Comment: You need to pass the adapter and list into your utility method in that case. I updated the code in my answer.