# Returning a value out of valueEventListenener in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem. The table `etd` contains objects of type `Etudiant` but I can't return these objects out of the listener :

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    Etudiant etud = new Etudiant();

    public Etudiant getEtud() {
        return etud;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int i = 0;
        Groupe groupe = new Groupe();
        Object[] objTab = new Object[100];
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(tabdesobjet(objTab,Groupe.class,dataSnapshot,i)),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int j = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot map: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (!map.getKey().equals("id") && !map.getKey().equals("idCycle") && !map.getKey().equals("idFilliere") && !map.getKey().equals("idPromo") && !map.getKey().equals("idSection") && !map.getKey().equals("nbEtudiants") && !map.getKey().equals("designation")) {
                objTab[i] = map.getValue();
                i++;
            }

        }
        Etudiant[] etd = new Etudiant[i];
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            HashMap < String, Object > hashMap = (HashMap < String, Object > ) objTab[j];
            etd[j] = new Etudiant();
            etd[j].setAttributs(hashMap);
        }
        Log.v("Test", "Etudiant = " + etd[0].getNom());
        etud = etd[0];
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by you cannot return the object out of the listener. Are you getting a compilation issue? or Runtime issue?

Comment: Data is loaded asynchronously from the Firebase Database. By the time you're trying to return a value, the code in `onDataChange` hasn't run yet. Instead of trying to return a value, move the code the *uses* the value *into* `onDataChange`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372562/returning-a-value-in-firebase-ondatachange

Comment: Thank you, but my program is too big it is a real application, I am blocked,help me .

Answer (score 0):

first it's easyer to use Collections like `List<Etudiant>` or `ArrayList<Etudiant>` , second i didn't get what you want to do exactly

Comment: I went to get data and use it in my program .

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
ArrayList<Etudiant> etudiantList = new ArrayList<>();

void getEtudiantList() {
     mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                etudiantList.add(snapshot.getKey());
            }             
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```